# Removing user from MUC member list

Tags: xmpp, multiuserchat

Is there a way a user can remove himself from a XMPP Multi-User Chat member list without being necessarily an owner or admin (i.e., change his affiliation from member to none)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [XEP 045 about MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roles-priv)   (section 5.2.2) clearly states that affiliation changes from member to none requires an Admin or an Owner to change the affiliation, this is the third section in the table:
(for clarification, the table states an affiliation change, i.e.
 Member -> to -> none)

> Table 7: Affiliation State Chart
>
> Member | Admin or owner changes affiliation to "none"

So sorry but the answer is no, if you're looking for a way to do it that will be unnoticeable to the user - you might need another layer, or a web service that works as admin and make these changes in the background.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, apparently there is no way according to XEP-0045. The solution I found was to create a bot in (in Python, using SleekXMPP) responsible for managing this kind of stuff (pretty much what you said about the additional layer).